What exacly is passManager and passes in qiskit?
I am trying to understand what exactly is passManager, what exactly it its use, where exactly we need to use it?
https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/circuits_advanced/04_transpiler_passes_and_passmanager.ipynb
The link above provide some information about passManager.
The have provided some code also as shown below:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.compiler import transpile
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager

circ = QuantumCircuit(3)
circ.ccx(0, 1, 2)
print(circ.draw())


from qiskit.transpiler.passes import Unroller # NOTE: Unroller is not supported by qiskit_1.0

pass_ = Unroller(['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'])
pm = PassManager(pass_)
new_circ = pm.run(circ)
print(new_circ.draw())


It would be great if I can be helped in this. Not sure whether is it the passManager which has changed this ccx gate into some kind of random circuit?

passManager allows us to manage and schedule the execution of transpiler passes on quantum circuits. Transpiler passes are transformations or optimizations applied to the circuit to improve its complexity (e.g., gate count, circuit connectivity, etc.) or make it more suitable for a specific hardware platform. In your case, the pass reexpresses a three-qubit gate in terms of one- and two-qubit gates. This is often done because a compiler wants only one- and two-qubit gates.
For example, we could define two passes: one pass removes redundant gates in a circuit, and another pass may merge multiple gates into a single gate. Then, we create a passManager to determine which passes are executed and in which order.
One of many applications of passManager is in Hamiltonian simulation. In this application venue, quantum circuits may contain a sequence of gates that could be merged into a single gate, or a circuit may contain multi-qubit gates that need to be reexpressed with one- and two-qubit gates. To achieve the desired changes and optimizations, we use passes and a passManager.
For example, consider the following toy circuit:

Those $CX$ gates are cancelling each other out. Also, two Hadamard gates are redundant because $HH=I$.
If we now setup passManager with passes that do clean up, we get the optimized circuit:

Of course, the circuit above was trivial, but in a practical scenario, e.g., a Hamiltonian simulation, we will have a circuit with millions of gates on dozens of qubits, and it may hide lots of redundancies. Those circuits may need many different optimization and transformation passes, which can take hours to run. For this, we want a way to manage our passes, and this is what passManager can do.
Here is the toy code with comments to reproduce the figures above:
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import CXCancellation, CommutativeCancellation, Optimize1qGates

# Create a quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.cx(0, 1)  # These CNOTs are redundant
qc.h(0)
qc.h(0)  # These Hadamards should ideally cancel to identity

# Create a PassManager
pass_manager = PassManager()

# Add optimization passes
# CXCancellation(): A pass that cancels consecutive CNOT gates.
# CommutativeCancellation(): A pass that cancels adjacent gates that commute.
# Optimize1qGates(): A pass that optimizes consecutive single-qubit gates.

# First, cancel CNOTs, then cancel Hadamards
pass_manager.append([CXCancellation(), CommutativeCancellation()])

# Run the PassManager on the quantum circuit
optimized_qc = pass_manager.run(qc)

# Print the original and optimized circuits
print("Original Quantum Circuit:")
print(qc.draw())

print("\nOptimized Quantum Circuit:")
print(optimized_qc.draw())

Qiskit version:
{'qiskit-terra': '0.25.1',  'qiskit': '0.44.1'}

The code should also work with later versions 1.0 and 1.1.
PS: as for the circuit screenshots you posted, I hope you can figure it out now. You are given a three-qubit gate CCX, and then you run a pass to reexpress it in terms of other gates such as ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx']. This transformation could be necessitated by a compiler which requires single- and two-qubit gates ['u1', 'u2', 'u3', 'cx'].

Thank you for the response @MonteNero. In your code above you have used passManager but you have not used transpile. So, do I have to transpile it also before running it on  Hardware or simulator?

@Manu, as I wrote in my post, passMa ager runs transpiler passes. So passes are transpilation and are coming from the transpiler module.

Thank you for great help @MonteNero

Thank you for great help @MonteNero. It would be great if you can mention which qiskit version you have used. It will make this answer complete.

@Manu, I am glad it helped to better understand passmanager. I've added the qiskit version in the asnwer.

You should probably mention that your code still works fr Qiskit >= 1.0. Great answer otherwise :)

@TristanNemoz thanks.  Is it for sure that it will work for v 1.0 and 1.1? I was not aware that qiskit went so far ahead.

Yes, I've tested it with 1.0 and 1.1!

@TristanNemoz, cool thanks. I've added that info.
